# How to use the preprocessor directives @modernhindi in devanagari

Tags: indic, hindi

I am trying to write my name in devanagari. I am writing {\dn vipula kakkaRa}. I need the output विपुल कक्कड़. After reading the manual, I found this has to do with preprocessor directives @hindi, @modernhindi etc. How do I use the preprocessor directives @modernhindi in devanagari to get the required output. Following is first few line of the preamble

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{devanagari}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,latexsym,amscd,amssymb, makeidx, tocbibind,graphics}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage[inner=2cm,outer=2cm]{geometry}

\makeindex

\def\chaptername{{\dn  adhyAya}}

\def\appendixname{{\dn pari"si.s.tha}}

\def\contentsname{{\dn vi.saya sUcI}}

\pagenumbering{devanagari} %page numbers

\renewcommand\thechapter{\devanagari{chapter}}

\renewcommand\thesection{\devanagari{chapter}. \devanagari{section}}

\title{{\dn\dnoriginal{} sa.mkhyA siddhA.mta}}

\author{{\dn vipula kakkaRa}}
```

Comment: if you are using xetex or a recent lualatex bases on luahbtex, then you should be able just to put विपुल  in your source with no preprocessor needed.  But as you have shown no code nor said which tex system you are using it's hard to be specific

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  I am using Texnic Center with miktex in window operating system. The issue is not with विपुल but with कक्कड़.

Comment: miktex is the distribution but are you using xelatex? कक्कड़. should be the same, You should be able to use that script in the input not needing to enter it using the latin alphabet

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am not using xeletex. I have edited my question and given preamble there.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use xelatex these days, the preprocessing was necessary when tex had no support for indic scripts but with xelatex or luahbtex it is really _much_ easier to use the scripts directly.

Answer (score 1):

I get

[image]

from xelatex on this document

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\dv[Script=Devanagari]{Nirmala UI}% the font firefox used to show your question
\begin{document}

Something like {\dv विपुल कक्कड़.}

\end{document}
```

Although I can't really read this to check it is correct.