# Problem with typing in Devanagari

Tags: pdftex, indic

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{devanagari}
\begin{document}
    vasishta
\end{document}
```

The result I get is this. How to fix this problem? 
[image]

Comment: The `devanagari` package is an obsolete way of getting Devanagari text, and it doesn't work the way you seem to be using it. (1) For Indic scripts, use xelatex or lualatex to generate your PDF, unless you have special reasons to use pdftex specifically. (Search on this site for many examples…) (2) If you really need to use pdftex, then consider reading the documentation of the package you're using. :-)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I have no clue about how to use xelatex or lualatex. What should I do? What packages to use, how to change to xelatex.

Comment: See [the answer by Ulrike Fischer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2576/getting-started-to-xetex-for-devangari/2578#2578) or [the answer by Alan Munn here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99606/how-to-write-bengali-in-latex/99659#99659) etc. Just compile your document with `xelatex` or `lualatex` instead of using `pdflatex`.

Comment: (Maybe there should be a FAQ on this site (or somewhere else) for Indic scripts, with different solutions based on (1) Is your document mainly in English with occasional Indic language, or the other way around, (2) Do you need the Indic language in the Indic script or in Roman transliteration, (3) Do you have a way of typing directly in the Indic script (or pasting in that text) or do you want your `.tex source file to contain transliterated text, and (4) Are you free to use XeTeX/LuaTeX, or do you need to use pdfTeX for some reason. Etc.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR My document would fall in the first category. Occasional Indic language though not too little but far less comparitively. What do you think is the easiest way to this?

Comment: there  is a simple example here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/533228/1090  to use xelatex instead of pdflatex, on the commandline simply type xelatex instead of pdflatex, or if you are using an editor compile menu most will have an existing option to use xelatex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle in XeLaTeX certain letters like Ksh don't print properly like I would want.